# How to add a cover to a pdf file from an image and from a bash command line?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick-convert, pdftk

Given an image and a pdf file, say `image.png` and a `file.pdf`, I need to add the image as the first page of the pdf file, in order it has the same dimensions as the other pages, and in order to be recognized by any thumbnailer.

If I do :

```
size = `pdfinfo file.pdf | grep "Page size:" | awk '{print $3 "x" $5}'`
convert image.png -resize $size image.pdf && pdftk image.pdf file.pdf cat output tmp.pdf && mv tmp.pdf file.pdf
```

or instead of `pdftk`:

```
pdfunite image.pdf file.pdf tmp.pdf
```

The first page is created with the right size, but no thumbnail is created by the file manager as it is for other pdf files.

Comment: Works fine over here with Nautilus / Ubuntu 20.10. Do you get a thumbnail for `image.pdf`? Which thumbnailer are you using?